# Why do my cats get cuddly in these rooms only?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

My cats are almost one year old and I've had them for around 8-9 months. I've been noticing for a good month now that both of them enjoy cuddling in the toilet and bathroom. Yes, the toilet room is separate and on the opposite end of the corridor to the bathroom.

I will be quite blunt here - When I go to the toilet to do my stuff, my cats always ask me to open the door, only to get inside and go around my legs and jump on my lap. They look more joyous than they normally do. They jump towards my hand for a cuddle, they lick my fingers, bite them playfully, etc. I thought that it was something to do with the door being closed - as I read many other questions, cats 'panic' when the doors are closed anywhere! - but turns out it makes no difference. I went once without closing the door and the same thing happened.

Then at some point the same thing kept happening in the bathroom, whenever for example I was brushing my teeth, washing hands, or anything else. They'd go around my legs and do everything mentioned previously.

They don't ever do that in any other rooms. They'd obviously stick their head out for some head scratching but that lasts for a few seconds. In the toilet room and bathroom it can last for half an hour.

Is there anything weird about this? Or is this something completely okay?

Comment: In my case, it's probably because I let them play with the running sink when they were younger.There's also the fact that you are, generally the most interesting thing happening in the house. Still... "Hey, do I demand attention while _you're_ in the litterbox?" (They never answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is not a cause for concern, or even especially unusual.

I've always assumed it was something that I'd unintentionally reinforced (I'm sitting here with my hands unoccupied and a cat wanders in. Hey kitty come here I'll pet you). We had one cat who would coming RUNNING and jump in your lap as soon as you sat down. But honestly, I'm not sure why they do it.